# Custom formatting of the elements of std::vectors using the fmt library

Tags: c++, fmt

While I can use `<fmt/ranges.h>` to readily output the contents of a `std::vector<T>`, I'm at a loss to format the display of its *elements* according to my preferences.

```
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

int main() {
    double x1 = 1.324353;
    double x2 = 4.432345;
    std::vector<double> v = {x1, x2};
    fmt::print("{}\n", v); // OK [1.324353, 4.432345]
    fmt::print("{:+5.2}\n", x1); // OK +1.3
    // fmt::print("{:+5.2}\n", v); // Does not compile!
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The program outputs:

```
[1.324353, 4.432345]
 +1.3
```

but is missing the desired output from the commented out line in my code above

```
[ +1.3, +4.4]
```

I then tried implementing a custom formatter for vectors of ordinary type but my attempt comes up short:

```
// custom formatter for displaying vectors
template <typename T>
struct fmt::formatter<std::vector<T>> : fmt::formatter<T> {
    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context &ctx) {
        return ctx.begin();
    }

    template <typename FormatContext>
    auto format(std::vector<T> v, FormatContext &ctx) {
        std::vector<std::string> v_str;
        v_str.reserve(v.size());
        const auto fmt_str = [&]() {
            if constexpr (std::is_integral<T>::value) {
                return "{:+5}";
            } else if constexpr (std::is_floating_point<T>::value) {
                return "{:+5.2}";
            } else {
                return "{}";
            }
        }();
        for (auto &e : v) {
            v_str.push_back(fmt::format(fmt_str, e));
        }
        return format_to(ctx.out(), "{}", v);
    }
};
```

The compiler complains

```
type_traits:3174:38: error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'formatter<std::vector<double>>'
    : public integral_constant<bool, __is_constructible(_Tp, _Args...)>
```

How do I get the `fmt` library to display the contents of a vector with custom formatting? The version I'm currently using is `8.1.1`.

Comment: Tweak this to provide full demo: https://godbolt.org/z/zdq8Ma8zE - this behaves differently then you have described.

Comment: Thanks @Marek R, I have. Just let me know if you'd like me to add anything else.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/8.1.1/test/ranges-test.cc#L235-L245

Comment: And specify your version of fmt.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/c46MdbbEx :)

Comment: Your custom formater competes with already existing implementation. I have no idea how you could resolve this ambiguity. I would just use existing implementation.

Comment: @Marek R, yeah that was my guess too: that there's a conflict. Thanks for the fix though. You're amazing!

Comment: The only why I can think this could be resolved is by providing some proxy type (some custom type you can provide own implementation of formater). This will look exactly as `fmt::jon` so why to bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
std::vector<double> v = {1.324353, 4.432345};
fmt::print("{::+5.2}\n", v);
```

This prints:

```
[ +1.3,  +4.4]
```

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nno838x9x)

Note the extra `:`. Format specifiers after the first colon (empty in this case) apply to the vector itself. Specifiers after the second colon (`+5.2`) apply to elements.

Comment: Thanks @vitaut . It would also be great if you could direct us to where the use of double `:`s is documented. I'd also like to point out that this feature works for `fmt` v.9.0.0 but not for older versions (v.8.1.1 in particular) .

Comment: I have also not seen this anywhere. And saves me so much trouble!

Comment: It even works with nested vectors and one can control the brackets, see here: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/blob/b0c8263cb26ea178d3a5df1b984e1a61ef578950/test/ranges-test.cc#L29-L78